# Downgrade Python 3.10 to 3.9 in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, downgrade

It looks like there is a compatibility issue with PyTorch and Python 3.10 when I want to use google Colab.
I need to use !pip install torch==1.8 torchvision==0.9 but this problem don't let me.
I should do Downgrading.

I need to get code to downgarde Python version.

Comment: I don´t think you can choose a Python version in google colab: it is their infrastructure.
Just install and run Python yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem. It seems to be due to an 'upgrade' pushed to Colabs.  I think this addresses that 'upgrade':
https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/3646#issuecomment-1570238781

There's maybe more to it than this, but this is how I downgraded python in my colabs notebook:

```
!sudo apt-get update -y
!sudo apt-get install python3.8 -y
!echo 2 | sudo update-alternatives --config python3 #'echo 2' auto-inputs '2' so that it doesn't have to be done manually
```

I hope this helps.  Good luck.

Comment: I do this but when I check the version, it still says Python 3.10.12?

Comment: HI Lizardinablizzard, I think since I posted that answer, yet again, Colab changed it's back end so that it's more complicated now to run an older version of python. Long story short, I gave up with Colab and switched to AWS EC2 and now run a Docker container for my environment.  EC2 is more expensive and requires more technical know how, but it's very stable and reliable.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Below is a method to **downgrade Python**. But you should note that every time you want to use the **conda** environment to install or work with it, you must first use this script `! source activate env_name;` **or** easily use `%%bash` first of cells to activate it, then write the command you want **exactly** after this script.

## Step 1:

`! python --version`

## Step 2:

`!pip install -q condacolab`

`import condacolab`

`condacolab.install()`

## Step 3:

`!conda --version`

## Step 4:

you should choose a python version from the output of this code and replace to `PYTHON_VERSION` in next step:
`!conda search python`

## Step 5:

`! conda create -n env_name python=PYTHON_VERSION # PYTHON_VERSION can be 3.9 or any other releas`

## Step 6:

you should create a `requirements.txt` file and place **name of all packages** which you need to install on it.

## Step 7:

`! source activate env_name; python --version; pip -V; pip install -r requirements.txt`